# Adding a Value Attribute to on a AspxButton

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

```
  <dxe:ASPxButton ID="getProgram" runat="server" Text="Programs" SkinID="MenuButton" OnClick="Button_Click">
  </dxe:ASPxButton>
```

Here is my Code Behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {              
            this.getProgram.Attributes.Add("Value", "View Progams Button");
        }
```

I tried this it didn't work. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? A button normally doesn't have a value property.

Comment: I am trying to do it for 508 compliant purposes. Since the AspxButton genereates an Input element with a type button, only way I can remove the Wave error is by adding a value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a `<dxe:ASPxButton>` is but a regular `<asp:Button>` has its `value` property set via the 'Text' attribute: -

`<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="click me :)" />`

[image: What gets rendered]